# Using cd command on Terminal Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

Hello I'm new on terminal.

Can someone explain what is the difference between cd /Applications and cd Applications

Answer (score 2):

It depends on in which path you run `cd Applications`.

Run `pwd` to print the current working directory. You usually are in your home directory, when opening a fresh terminal. So it should be `/Users/you/Applications`.

A path starting with a `/` is an absolute path, so always `/Applications`.